# Server to provide VM to a thin client

Tags: virtual-machine, thin-client

I have a strong server and 2 thin clients.
I'm looking for opensource software so i can stream or provide a VM from the server to the thin client. My plan is that the thin client will have to use pxe boot, to boot into the vm.

Anyone has a solution for this ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you done a research on google? I just entered "opensource vm server thin client" and got a ton of results. Some are: LTSP, OpenThinClient, FreeNX/ThinStation. Your question is a little bit vague to make a specific suggestion.

Comment: Next thing a wanted to ask if someone has some experience with it? What is best / easiest to setup... ?
And if it's available, a good tutorial on how to setup the server and thin client.